# MS ACCESS SQL - Checking A Digit Retrieved from Column IN WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ms-access-2003

I WANT TO retrieve records by Checking N place digit from FIELD 'NUMBER' EQUALS to 7

```
  $product=pow(10,4-n);  
    $product1=pow(10,4-n+1);

    $query="SELECT * FROM Classes 
       WHERE(((FLOOR(NUMBER/".$product."))-(FLOOR(NUMBER/".$product1.")*10)))=7";
```

FILED 'NUMBER' is a 4-digit number always...

HELP, this is generating an error

> is there any better methosd for doing this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substrings

For example

If you want to take Nth digit from left:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Classes WHERE SUBSTRING(NUMBER, $n, 1) = 7"
```

or from right:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Classes WHERE SUBSTRING(NUMBER, -$n, 1) = 7"
```